# is there any efficient way to search information in a big remote XML file?

Tags: ios, xml, cocoa, parsing

I'm working in an iOS app, and the client wants that the app performs a search in a XML that his server provides. The problem is that the file size is about 6MB. So a download plus parse plus search, could take a lot of time. So I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to perform this task? Or it has to be done in a different way (without XML file at all)?

Comment: well, let the server perform the search and only send the result to the client then would be my first idea.

Comment: Any solution will have to involve either some sort of remote indexing or caching, or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, what you should do is define an API and let the server do the parsing and retrieval of the information you need on the device.

This approach has many advantages and is the most appropriate unless your app is required to work offline. In such case, the only available option is to download the file and parsing it locally, but, as you see, this will have its own cost in term of required time.